# Bootstrap container-fluid has a left and right margin

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a navigation bar that has a full width layout, I have created the container-fluid class acting as the navigation wrapper and within is the row class followed by the columns.... as far as I'm aware, this is the correct structure of bootstrap, yet I am getting a margin to both the left and right.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="header_category_icon">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-10">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="header_search_icon">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.header {
    height:50px;
    background-color:#222222;
}

.header_category_icon, .header_search_icon {
    background-color:#575757;
    height:50px;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note `col-sm-*`'s are supposed to be direct children of `.row`s:

```html
<div class="container-fluid header">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
       ...
```

Working example:

```css
.header>.row>[class^="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            This is an example
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take a closer look at Bootstrap examples.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this but the navigation does not span the full width, instead it is padded by two white gaps wither side

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] I'll tell you what's causing that. It's something in your CSS.

Comment: Thats odd, In safari the white gaps show, in jsfiddle they dont https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32252/

Comment: See the updated answer, I added an example. I also removed the `col-sm-1`s.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed this same structure however get this white margin : www.specced.co.uk

Comment: That's because you're adding `background-color` to `.header_category_icon` instead of adding it to the `.col` (which has left and right padding). Also, I don't understand why you don't apply `.header` to either `.row` or `.container-fluid` (to `.row` if it's only one row - to `.container-fluid` if your header has more than one `.row`). You don't need the extra wrapper. Updated my answer with proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help - The issue was jointly that the col-XX-XX was not a child of the container-fluid, also the header_category_icon & header_search_icon did not need child classes, they could be instead be within the col class like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid header">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-1 header_category_icon">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1 header_search_icon">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```